# Replace multiple replaceAll with a cleaner way of coding in a string

Tags: java, android

I need to perform multiple `replaceAll` commands in a string and i wonder if there is a clean way to do it. This is how it is currently:

```
newString = oldString.replaceAll("α","a").replaceAll("β","b").replace("c","σ") /* This goes on for over 60 replacements*/;
```

Comment: Do it using a for loop. Have a map which will have keys as greek letters and values as latin equivalents and loop through it and perform replacing. Because, in the end you still have to have that mappings to know which letter changes to what.

Comment: You could use [`replace(char, char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) instead of `replaceAll`, since you're not using regular expressions. Or you could use a stringbuilder, which would reduce the number of copies you're having to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented a specialized solution if you only want to replace a single `Character` with a single `Character` or another `String`:

```
private static Map<Character, Character> REPLACEMENTS = new HashMap<>();
static {
    REPLACEMENTS.put('α','a');
    REPLACEMENTS.put('β','b');
}

public static String replaceChars(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length();++i) {
        char currentChar = input.charAt(i);
        sb.append(REPLACEMENTS.getOrDefault(currentChar, currentChar));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This implementation avoids excessive string copies / complex regexes and thus should perform really well compared to an implementation that uses either `replace` or `replaceAll`. You can change the replacement to `String` too but replacing whole `String`s instead of `Characters` is more complicated - I would prefer a regex then.

EDIT:
Here is a solution for whole `String`s in the above style but I would recommend you to look into other solutions like e.g. regex as its performance characteristics are not as good as the above example for `Character`. Furthermore its more complex and error prone, a simple test showed it's working correctly though. It still avoids the string copies though so it may be preferable in performance sensitive scenarios.

```
private static Map<String, String> REPLACEMENTS = new HashMap<>();
static {
    REPLACEMENTS.put("aa","AA");
    REPLACEMENTS.put("bb","BB");
}
    public static String replace(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        i += replaceFrom(input, i, sb);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static int replaceFrom(String input, int startIndex, StringBuilder sb) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> replacement : REPLACEMENTS.entrySet()) {
        String toMatch = replacement.getKey();
        if (input.startsWith(toMatch, startIndex)) {
            sb.append(replacement.getValue());
            //we matched the whole word skip all matched characters
            //not just the first
            return toMatch.length() - 1;
        }
    }
    sb.append(input.charAt(startIndex));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does this method also work for replacing a sequence of characters? example "abcd" to "e". EDIT: I just saw you mentioned this only works for a single character...

Comment: No, as I have explained: replacing multiple input characters needs a more complex solution. I will add it to my answer

Comment: Do you have the complex solution handy? because i do need to replace multiple characters.

Comment: I added the extended solution, use with care

Comment: One last question. In my own line i used newString and oldString. Which elements in your code correspond to them?

Comment: You call `replace` with your `oldString` and the return value is your `newString`. I have used a StringBuilder (`sb`) that buffers all the parts before creating the transformed input via `sb.toString()`. In short `oldString`= `input` parameter of `replace`, `newString` = result of `sb.toString()`

Comment: Alright i am gonna make the symbol map and try the code. I ll be back at you later. :)

Comment: I would advise you to use a simple regex as my solution still suffers from iteration order issues when you replace two equally starting strings like `aa` and `aaa`. Depending on the map entrySet iteration order the input `aaa` could be replaced in differing ways. I also had to adjust it to not consider parts that were already replaced (see updated code) and it's considerably more complex now

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Map will contain the mappings and all you have to do is to loop through the mappings and call `replace`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your input
    String old = "something";
    // the mappings
    Map<Character, Character> mappings = new HashMap<>();
    mappings.put('α','a');
    // loop through the mappings and perform the action
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Character> entry : mappings.entrySet()) {
        old = old.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```